# Верно ли стоят запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

*Отчасти так и было, но что только «отчасти», Тони начал понимать уже позже.*

Comment: Пунктуация верна.

Comment: Kate, у Вас остались ещё какие-то вопросы по поводу моего ответа? Спрашивайте, порассуждаем дальше.

Comment: @Kate Liechtenschtein, вы  перестали принимать ответы на ваши вопросы (7 последних ответов). Это можно как-то объяснить?

Answer (score 2):

***Отчасти так и было, но что только «отчасти», Тони начал понимать уже позже.***

Например, [**здесь**](https://ficbook.net/readfic/11742894/30457804) второй запятой нет.
Но я бы поставил эту запятую, поскольку после союза НО пропущено сказуемое: *Отчасти так и было, но что только «отчасти»* [так и было], *Тони начал понимать уже позже.* (Запятая отделяет неполное изъяснительое придаточное предложение.)

P. S. Грамматически возможна еще одна запятая: после НО. Но она нежелательна ввиду интонационной слитности НО и ЧТО.

**Дополнение** после комментария Sharon (спасибо!)

Да, запятая после НО уместна (никто не придерётся – всё по правилам). Но...
Справочник Розенталя, [**Запятая на стыке двух союзов**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140):

> 5. Постановка запятой между присоединительным союзом (в начале предложения, после точки) и следующим за ним подчинительным союзом зависит от значения союза:
>    <...>
>    **3)** после союза ***но*** запятая ставится при наличии паузы между союзами и не ставится, если паузы нет; ср.: ***Но, если** далее противнику удавалось отбить атакующих, пехота снова бросалась в атаку* (Сим.); ***Но когда** он, опираясь на палку, вышел из штабного автобуса на площадь… и, не ожидая, пока его обнимут, сам стал обнимать и целовать всех, кто попадал в его объятия, что-то защемило в ране* (Павл.)
>    <...>
>    **Примечание.**
>    <...>
>    **3)** перед придаточной частью запятая ставится в зависимости от значения присоединительного союза и наличия/отсутствия паузы при чтении.

Считаю указание на **начало предложения (после точки)** формальным. То есть если мы ставим точку **перед** НО, постановка запятой **после** этого союза зависит от интонации (воли автора), а если ставим запятую, то обязательна ещё одна? В чём принципиальное отличие? Какая разница между началом после точки и началом после запятой?
Думаю, что союз НО относится ко всему сложноподчинённому предложению и запятая после него не нужна.

Comment: Я голосую за ваш ответ, так как запятая поставлена верно: здесь неполное изъяснительное придаточное. Но отсутствие запятой после союза НО тоже надо объяснять – ведь структурная перестановка придаточного возможна, и тогда по правилам запятая ставится. На интонацию обращать внимание не приходится, так как пауза при встрече союзов отсутствует в любом случае.